# Outputting content from page

Tags: pages, post-thumbnails, page-template

I'm trying to display a title, featured image, and content from a page into a new template (that will contain content from several pages). I tried to just echo the variables as shown below, but right now it's only display the content and title+"array". Any ideas?

Here is my current array:

```
 <?php
 $id = 2131;
 $post = get_page($id);
 $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
 $title = $post->post_title;
 $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'single-post-    
 thumbnail' );
 echo $content;
 echo $title;
 echo $image;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**wp_get_attachment_image_src returns an array**, not a single value. Please refer to this article for more info: [wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src)

**Default Usage**

```
<?php 
$attachment_id = 8; // attachment ID

$image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id ); // returns an array
?> 

<img src="<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $image_attributes[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $image_attributes[2]; ?>">
```

Comment: That makes sense, but I'm confused what the syntax would look like to just return the image in an image tag from my original array?

Comment: @mtthwbsh Try this: `echo $image[0];`